# How to display option value into a text input

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below I have a form which contains four text inputs:

```
<form id='updateForm'>

        <p><strong>Current Assessment's Date/Start Time:</strong></p>
        <table>
         <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Assessment:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Start Time:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly' value=''/> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>    
    </form>
```

Now below I have a drop down option which goes at:

```
$sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' style='color: %s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $class, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
```

Now what I am doing is that the values displayed in the drop down menu is displayed in their relevant text inputs using this code below:

```
$('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){
        if( $(this).val() !== '' ){
            var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            var split = text.split(' - ');
            $('#currentAssessment').val( split[0] );     
            $('#currentDate').val( split[1] );     
            $('#currentTime').val( split[2] );     
        }
    });
```

But the only problem I am having is how do I display the value of the option which is `<option value='%s' ... $dbSessionId ...` to be displayed in the text input `#currentId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#currentId').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());
```